# Add content for the URL data.stackexchange/sitename

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

So you start at the [Data Explorer start page](https://data.stackexchange.com/), and then you click on the [Stack Overflow site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

And then a couple of days later, when you start typing the URL in your browser, you remove the last parts of the URL and you try to visit https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/ . But then you get "Page Not Found". (This has happened to me more than once)

**It does not make any sense** that https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/ leads to "Page Not Found".

Suggestion:

When visiting https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/ , redirect to https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: I actually don't dislike the way Edgar F. Codd looks at me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes a lot of sense, so now [it's done](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/16) pending a pull and redeploy of Data Explorer.

I also added a redirect for the domain prefixes of each site, since some of the paths are kind of obnoxious to type. As an example, [Database Administrators](https://data.stackexchange.com/database%20administrators/queries) will now be accessible via `/dba` and `/dba/queries` by way of a redirect to the current URL.

I think in the future switching to use the domain-based URL probably makes the most sense, but I didn't want to risk breaking something with that change right now.